# How do I troubleshoot DB Error: connect failed on a new installation on Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, database, installation

I am following the detailed instructions to install Civi under Wordpress. I am running a local development Wordpress site using MariaDB 10. I have downloaded and activated the CiviCRM plugin. The CiviCRM installer is accessible. I have created a new empty database and user for CiviCRM and I can get a full "Green" ("You're ready to install") from the installer. But when I click on "Check requirements and install" I get an error:

"Cannot open mysql://[user]:[password]@localhost:3307/[path_to_database]?new_link=true: DB Error: connect failed."

The server port number is correct for this installation.

Any idea where I can look for more detail on why the connection fails at this stage?

Comment: The issue might be the [path_to_database], can you tell us what is the value for that? Also try to set your php.ini to make the default port for mysql and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. The [path_to_database] is @localhost:3307/run/mysqld/mysqld10.sock/databasename. I'll look at php.ini.

Comment: Normally for a tcp socket you don't include the "unix socket" path. Try just the database name, e.g. @localhost:3307/databasename

Answer (score 1):

The php mysql extension is no longer supported. Need to use mysqli. See
https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/psa-please-verify-php-extension-mysqli

The web server log might also indicate the error.

Comment: Many thanks. Running phpinfo shows that mysqli is enabled. But when I run the php command line query suggested in the link you posted, it returns "missing".  So I'll keep looking at that. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by demerit, it is not necessary to specify the "unix socket" path in the server details. On the "CiviCRM Installer" page, in the server details, enter only [servername] and optional [:port] if port is not default.